# LinkedList reads root's value twice

Tags: c, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

When I type first value of linked list, console writes same value twice. For example, If I type a, it writes aa and then it goes normally.

```
if (r == NULL) { // If our list is empty...
    r = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
    r->x = i;
    r->next = NULL;
    r->prev = NULL;
    iter = r;
    last = r;
    printf("%c", i);
}

if (iter == last) {
    node* temp = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp-> x = i;
    temp->prev = last;
    last->next = temp;
    temp->next = NULL;
    last = temp;
    iter = last;
    printf("%c", i);
}
```

How can I fix it? I used `getch()` to get characters.

Comment: Could you post more of your loop?

Comment: `if (iter == last)`  ==> `else if (iter == last)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a bunch of useful code from your listing, but basically it will always print twice when creating the root node because both `if` blocks will be executed. If you don't want them both executed, try using `else if` for the second block.

Answer (score 0):

Add an else before your second if clause.
It is entirely possible that r is null, then immediately after, the condition for your second if clause stipulates

```
if(iter==last)
```

where in the prior if clause you do the following

```
iter = r;
last = r;
```

Therefore iter is equal to last and the second if clause gets executed.

Alternately you could do the following:

1. Add a `break` at the end of each `if` clause
2. Save off what you want to print to a local variable, then print it in one place (the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)), and IMHO, the best suited for this situation